# How bright would the surface of each planet be?

Tags: optics, visible-light, astronomy, estimation, planets

At night when there is no moon in the sky, it is dark, you can not see your surroundings. If I were to stand on Pluto, could I see my surroundings? Would being on pluto at day be like night on earth in terms of visibility? Or perhaps on the surface of Europa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [illuminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminance) of full daylight on the surface of the Earth is about 10,000 [lux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux). Jupiter is about five times as far from the Sun as the Earth, and Pluto is between thirty and fifty times as far from the Sun as the Earth (depending on where it is in its orbit). So daytime illuminance on the surface of Europa will be about 400 lux and on Pluto it will be between 4 and 10 lux (applying the inverse square law). For simplicity, I have ignored the effect of the Earth’s atmosphere here.

For comparison, 100 lux is the equivalent of an overcast day on Earth; 10 lux is the equivalent of twilight on Earth; and the illuminance from a full moon on Earth is about 0.1 lux.